# Linked List delete function exception

Tags: c++

I have some study to do for an upcoming C++ assessment and I have an issue with my deleteNode function. I know the problem lies somewhere within the function as I copied a previous deleteNode function and it worked fine.All of my other pushback/pushfront functions work fine, I'd rather know the problem than just ignore it but I can't spot it for the life of me.

So the linked list is storing Employees, with a name (string) and a salary (double). My deleteNode matches the name of the employee and the string parameter passed in. If anyone can spot my mistake it'll be a great help to my learning!

```
bool EmployeeList::deleteNode(std::string n){
EmployeeNode *leadptr = head, *trailptr = nullptr;

if (head != nullptr){
    if (head->emp.name == n){
        head = head->next;
        delete leadptr;
        return true;
    }
    else{
        while (leadptr != nullptr && leadptr->emp.name != n){
            trailptr = leadptr;
            leadptr = leadptr->next;
        }
        if (leadptr = nullptr){
            return false;
        }
        else{
            trailptr->next = leadptr->next;  //access violation here, leadptr may be null
            delete leadptr;
            return true;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `if (leadptr = nullptr)` You need `==` here.

Comment: _@Mark Lordan_ This could have been easily detected when compiling with all warnings switched on, or at least reading those warning messages you get.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I received no warning messages, just an access violation with no helpful info. Could you explain how I get these warning options?

Comment: @MarkLordan Depends on your toolchain, but for GCC it's `-Wall`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an assignment

```
    if (leadptr = nullptr){
```

Correction would be

```
    if (leadptr == nullptr){
```

Comment: @MarkLordon Errors like this are already cought by the compiler (they are just called warnings: warnings are logical errors in your code). Your code should compile with zero warnings. You can get the compiler to treat warnings like errors with a simple flag so that you see these logical errors. I would also increase the aggressiveness of the warnings (with more flags turning more warnings on).